# How should I use libsodium to encrypt and decrypt an API key that my user type in? Frontend is javascript, backend is python and postgres

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, libsodium

I'm building a website on Django 3.2 using postgres 14 as database.

I will call cloudflare API on behalf of the user using the user's CloudFlare API key.

Given that the API key is sensitive, I wanted to have the user type in a webform and encrypt it before sending it back to my backend to be decrypted.

I read about libsodium (See [how do I encrypt data?](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:J3JShQr0lI0J:https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/quickstart%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sg) I used cached because for some reason the website is temporarily down)

And I understand that github themselves [use it for github secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.3/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#using-secrets) so I guess what's good enough for github is good enough for me.

However, I am confused about the workflow.

Because even for crypto_secretbox_easy there's still a need for key. How do I share the key between the frontend form (in HTML and javascript) and the backend server (python)?

I am likely to use libsodium.js for the javascript and pynacl for python.

My related questions scneario-wise are:

1. suppose the user key in the cloudflare API key in the form, so when they submit the form, what's submitted in the payload will be the encrypted version of the API key, the backend simply takes that and stores it in the database specific to that user. Is this correct?
2. suppose when the time comes, the user initiates a command where i need to perform an action in cloudflare on their behalf. So my python code will fetch the encrypted API key from the database and decrypt it and then calls CloudFlare API using that API key. Is this correct?
3. Suppose after the user submitted the cloudflare API key in the form in scenario 1, and subsequently revisits the same form, do I decrypt the API key and show it to the user in the form as value to the input text element? Or it's safer I show only the last 4 characters of the plaintext of the original API key and the rest as asterisk.

If the user still wants to change the API key, they can. And the process will be as per scenario 1. Is this right?

In all 3 scenarios, I am unsure how and where to generate and store the nonce and related keys.

I am also unsure whether to use public keys or secret key encryption.

Thank you

Comment: Encryption is handled by SSL. While there have been times where holes in its security appeared, they are few and far between, and it is generally trusted by pretty much everyone on the web, including banks/payment processors. As long as you have properly set up server (!), you can consider your communication between the browser and backend secure, with no extra work: libsodium is not required, or typically used in this scenario.

Comment: ok, i understand. Suppose I rephrase my question as I want to follow github example of using libsodium sealed boxes to store secrets on behalf of users. What does that mean?